# Creating Custom List Definition in sharepoint 2010 using Wsp Builder Project. getting Error

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, wspbuilder

I have created new Wsp builder project and Added one feature.

In Element.xml file I have to Define the Custom List template.

I have Created the Custom List and named as Schema.xml.

I added the Schema.xml file in Feature and I have given the Corresponding location in the Feature.xml.

I deployed my solution and activate the Feature.

The Custom List template has come Under the Collaboration tab.when I am trying to Create List using the Custom List Template I am Getting Error

"**Invalid Filename the file name you specified could not be used. It may be the name of the Existing file or the Directory or You may not have Permission to access the File** "

MayI know where I am Going Wrong and how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please attach a screen shot of the project structure and your xml to provide more details